# How to take a text between "/" with Awk / cut?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, cut

I have this command in a script:

```
find /home/* -type d -name dev-env 2>&1 | grep -v 'Permiso' >&2 > findPath.txt
```

this gives me this back:

```
/home/user/project/dev-env
```

I need to take the second parameter between "/" (user) to save it later in a variable. I can not find the way to just pick up the "user" text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `cut`:

```
echo "/home/user/project/dev-env" | cut -d'/' -f3
```

Result:

```
user
```

This tells `cut` to use `/` as the delimiter and return the 3rd field. (The 1st field is blank/empty, the 2nd field is `home`.)

Using `awk`:

```
echo "/home/user/project/dev-env" | awk -F/ '{print $3}'
```

This tells `awk` to use `/` as the field-seperator and print the 3rd field.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the path resulting from the grep is always an absolute path:

```
second_component=$(find .... -type d -name dev-env 2>&1 | grep -v 'Permiso' | cut -d / -f 3)
```

However, your approach suffers from several other problems:

You use /home/* as starting point for `find`. This will work only, if there is exactly one subdirectory below /home. Not a very likely scenario.

Even then, it works only if grep results in exactly one line. This is a semantic problem: What if you get more than one line - which one are you interested in? Assume that you know that you are always interested into the first line, you can solve this by piping the result though `head -n 1`.

Next, you redirect the stderr from `find` to stdout, which means that any error from `find` remains unnoticed; you just get some weird result. It would be better to have any error message from `find` being displayed, and instead evaluate the exit code from `find` and `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

```
... | cut -d/ -f3
```

"Third field, as cut by slash delimiter"